# CiteULike API 'forbidden'

Tags: python, api, urllib2, http-status-code-403

I am trying to query counts of bookmarks for research papers in CiteULike. I am using the "http://www.citeulike.org/api/posts/for/doi/" URL in order to put in a request (using urllib2 library for Python) for an XML document which contains information on the bookmarks for a given DOI (unique identifier for papers). However I keep getting a HTTP 403 Error: Forbbiden.

Does anyone know why I am getting this error? I've tried putting the URL with the DOI in the browser and that returns the XML just fine, so the problem seems related to my automated requests.

Thanks,
Nathanael

Comment: Please show the code, and link to the API documentation. Otherwise, you're relying on people who (a) already know the CiteULike API or are willing to search for it, and (b) can guess what you might have done wrong.

Comment: But as a guess: Most APIs have some kind of auth requirements, and you may not be following the appropriate one. (Whether this means not doing OAuth, not passing back the session cookie you got, etc. is harder to guess.) Another common problem is that you just generated the wrong URL and your request looks like an attempt to browse a container that allows you to access its elements but not browser the container. Or you accessed a container that you _do_ have browse access to, over a REST API, but left off the trailing `/`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should read http://wiki.citeulike.org/index.php/Importing_and_Exporting#Scripting_CiteULike

> If you access CiteULike via an automated process, you MUST provide a
>   means to identify yourself via the User-Agent string. Please use
>   "<username>/<email> <application>" e.g., "fred/fred@wilma.com
>   myscraper/1.0". Any scripting of the site without a means to identify
>   you may result in a block.